# Delete "very" special characters from string

Tags: php, character

How to delete "very" special characters from string?

Characters like heart, star, bull, copyright etc.

I found this:

```
$re = "/\\p{S}/i";
$str = "asdas�sadsad";
$subst = "";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

but it's delete too much (eg. "+" char).

Comment: is there anything about any of these very special characters that are consistent?

Comment: What do you mean by "very special"? Maybe it would be better if you say what kind of characters should be *allowed*. Unicode currently has a little more than 100.000 defined characters.

Comment: google FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW or FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH

Comment: characters that are not entered from the keyboard (without Alt + NUMPAD)

Comment: @Maku123PL English keyboards? Japanese keyboards? German keyboards? So, if I wanted to thank you in German, "danke schön", should  it be spelled "danke schn"?

Comment: It's harder than I expected. I create a list where users can add entries. Some people use special characters to their posts more visible. My website is for Poles. The allowed characters here: http://pastebin.com/jQ9r7aUS + space

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `POSIX` character class `print` (ASCII ink-users plus widthful whitespace), i.e.:

```
$str = "asdas�sadsad";
$str = preg_replace('/[^[:print:]]/', '', $str);

echo $str;
```

output:

```
asdassadsad
```

Regex Explanation:

```
[^[:print:]]
```

- Match any character that is NOT in the `POSIX` character class `print` `«[^[:print:]]»`

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/XPE0cJ)

---

## Update based on your comments:

```
$str = "asdas�sadsad";
$str = preg_replace('/[^`1234567890qwertyuiop\[\]asdfghjkl;\'zxcvbnm,\.-~!@%\^&\*\(\)_\+\{\}:\|<>\?ąęćżźółńQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNMĄĘĆŻŹÓŁŃ]/i', '', $str);
echo $str;
```

Replaces all characters **NOT** on the list.

---

[<kbd>Demo 2</kbd>](http://ideone.com/7d3O8c)

Comment: @Rizier123 perfectionist ! :)

Comment: @Maku123PL the code doesn't convert, just replace. I think you've a problem with character encoding, try using `utf8_encode()` or `utf8_decode()` depending of what you need.

Comment: I just checked your list of allowed characters on pastebin, I'll make a new regex to remove any characters not on that list.